# laravel policy not called

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Does documention hides something, or there is something hidden?

created with

> php artisan make:policy AdvertisementPolicy --model=Advertisement

```
class AdvertisementPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any advertisements.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return false;

    }
public function view(User $user, Advertisement $advertisement)
{
    return false;

}
```

model was created with cli too

```
namespace App;

class Advertisement extends Model
{
```

Registered through:

```
use App\Advertisement;
use App\Policies\AdvertisementPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        Advertisement::class => AdvertisementPolicy::class,
```

Is here any additional steps to fulfill this policy registration with laravel 6?

Comment: where are you doing the authorization check that isn't using the policy?

Comment: at current time nowhere for this controller, but user is logged, i will include  within controller or routes auth middleware later, but i dont think here is problem for policy as didnt get policy called(with error at least)

Comment: well the policy is never going to be used if you are not doing an authorization check (specifically with that model) somewhere, so not sure what your question is ... so show where you are doing an actual 'authorization' check on some action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no something hidden in documentation. You just don't read the documentation carefully.

Please take a look at the [Authorizing Actions Using Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies) section.

Your policy is never called, because you don't use it anywhere in your code. Atleast, if you need to run your policy for your controller resources, you need to write something like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Advertisement;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdvertisementController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(Advertisement::class, 'advertisement');
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad if it helps ;)